# Radio button onclick to update form

Tags: javascript, html

When the credit card radio button is checked, I want the form to display user input for First name, Last name, address, city, state, zip, email, card holder name, card number, cvv2/cvc, exp date. When paypal radio button is checked, I want to display user input for paypal email address and paypal password.

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <meta charset-"utf-8">
   <title>Payment Processing Web Page</title>
   <script type= "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h2>Enter Payment Information</h2>
    <form onSubmit="return validateForm();">

     <label class = "containerRadio"><input name = "paymentType" type = "radio" value = "credit card" checked="checked"><span class = "radio"></span>
    Credit Card
     </label>

     <label class = "containerRadio"><input name = "paymentType" type = "radio" onclick="updateForm(this);" value = "paypal"><span class = "radio"></span>
    PayPal</a>
     </label>

 <div style="visibility:visable id="ccformContainer">
      //inputs for credit card form
 </div>
 <div style="visibility:hidden; id="paypalformContainer">
     //input for paypal form
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 function updateForm(control){


     if (control.checked) {
        document.getElementById("ccformContainer").style.visibility = 
         'hidden';
        document.getElementById("paypalformContainer").style.visibility = 
         'visible';


 }
```

Comment: Looks like your code contains too many errors.

Comment: I'm getting this error Uncaught ReferenceError: updateForm is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. So basically I resolved some errors and added actual logic to switch between credit card to Paypal and vice-versa.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Payment Processing Web Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Enter Payment Information</h2>
    <form onSubmit="return validateForm();">

        <label class="containerRadio"><input name="paymentType" type="radio" id="creditCard" value="credit card" checked="checked" onclick="updateForm(this);"><span class="radio"></span>
            Credit Card
        </label>

        <label class="containerRadio"><input name="paymentType" type="radio" id="paypal" onclick="updateForm(this);" value="paypal"><span class="radio"></span>
            PayPal
        </label>

        <div style="visibility:visable" id="ccformContainer">
            //inputs for credit card form
        </div>
        <div style="visibility:hidden;" id="paypalformContainer">
            //input for paypal form
        </div>
    </form>

</body>
<script>
    function updateForm(control) {
        if (control.id == "paypal") {
            document.getElementById("ccformContainer").style.visibility =
                'hidden';
            document.getElementById("paypalformContainer").style.visibility =
                'visible';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("paypalformContainer").style.visibility =
                'hidden';
            document.getElementById("ccformContainer").style.visibility =
                'visible';
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript is missing a closing bracket and your HTML is missing the end of double quotes for the styles (last two divs). You can see that directly on loading your script in Chrome, if you open the DevTools (f12 or right click + 'inspect'), there will be errors in the Console.

Here's the code with the missing stuff:

```js
function updateForm(control){


    if (control.checked) {
       document.getElementById("ccformContainer").style.visibility = 
        'hidden';
       document.getElementById("paypalformContainer").style.visibility = 
        'visible';
    }

}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset-"utf-8">
      <title>Payment Processing Web Page</title>
      <script type= "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h2>Enter Payment Information</h2>
       <form onSubmit="return validateForm();">
   
        <label class = "containerRadio"><input name = "paymentType" type = "radio" value = "credit card" checked="checked"><span class = "radio"></span>
       Credit Card
        </label>
   
        <label class = "containerRadio"><input name = "paymentType" type = "radio" onclick="updateForm(this);" value = "paypal"><span class = "radio"></span>
       PayPal</a>
        </label>
   
    <div style="visibility:visable" id="ccformContainer">
         //inputs for credit card form
    </div>
    <div style="visibility:hidden;" id="paypalformContainer">
        //input for paypal form
    </div>
```

However, your code doesn't really do what you need because your function updateForm() isn't called when you click on "Credit Card" radio button. If the user changes their mind, if breaks.

Do maybe something like this instead (can be improved):

```js
function updateForm(element) {
    if (element.id === "optionPp") {
        document.getElementById("ccformContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById("paypalformContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("ccformContainer").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("paypalformContainer").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset-"utf-8">
    <title>Payment Processing Web Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Enter Payment Information</h2>
    <form onSubmit="return validateForm();">

        <label class="containerRadio"><input id="optionCc" name="paymentType" type="radio" value="credit card" checked="checked"
                onclick="updateForm(this);"><span class="radio"></span>
            Credit Card
        </label>

        <label class="containerRadio"><input id="optionPp" name="paymentType" type="radio" onclick="updateForm(this);"
                value="paypal"><span class="radio"></span>
            PayPal</a>
        </label>

        <div style="visibility:visable" id="ccformContainer">
            //inputs for credit card form
        </div>
        <div style="visibility:hidden;" id="paypalformContainer">
            //input for paypal form
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```